# ASP-Url Routing without MVC giving problems

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I am having problems with asp 4.0 routing.

i have methods in Global.cs

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{  
    routes.MapPageRoute("cats","Categories/{ct}/{catname}","~/catwise.aspx");  
}
```

and

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  
}
```

and on my master page

```
<a href="Categories/<%# Eval("Category_Id")%>/<%# Eval("Category_Name")%>">
```

this is working perfectly in first routing like `Categories/1/Apple` but now after first routing all the links are double fro routed page like `Categories/1/Apple/Categories/2/Banana`.

The links are climbing on each other so the page shows `Resource not found`
 i tried setting `Base` but it made the matters worse.
I am not using any custom handlers

how should i solve this problem?/why is it not working properly?

tried using `/` before url like   `<a href="/Categories/<%# Eval("Category_Id")%>/<%# Eval("Category_Name")%>">`  but it said `resource not found` so added `/` in   `routes.MapPageRoute("cats","/Categories/{ct}/{catname}","~/catwise.aspx");`
but it threw compile time error saying url cannot contan `/` or `~` or `?`.

Comment: What is the home page URL when you are testing the site? Is it something like `http://localhost:1234` or `http://localhost:1234/mysite`. If its the former the `/` should work

Comment: home page url is `http://localhost:14268/mysite`

Comment: That is the reason `/` doesn't work. It gives `http://localhost:14268/Categories/1/Apple` instead of the correct `http://localhost:14268/mysite/Categories/1/Apple`. The funny thing is that in production is going to work... Anyway, see my last edit in my post below, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Routing issue. The problem is with the link. I don't know if the is a better way to generate links in Web Pages but a quick fix would be to simply add a `/`:

```
<a href="/Categories/<%# Eval("Category_Id")%>/<%# Eval("Category_Name")%>">
```

EDIT:

When you are in the home page `http://mysite/` and the browser see a "relative" link like `Categories/1/Apple` it adds that to the current path so the outcome is `http://mysite/Categories/1/Apple`. Because your link is relative to the page, the next time you hit the link the browser adds that again and you have `http://mysite/Categories/1/Apple/Categories/1/Apple`. The quick fix I proposed is about changing your relative link to absolute by adding a leading `/`.

The whole issue has nothing to do with asp.net and its routing. Its about how the browser treats relative links. I think there are more proper ways to generate links (when using routing), like:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:ct=1,catname=Apples,routename=cats%>">
    Link Text
</asp:HyperLink>
```

In the data binding scenario you can try:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkClient" runat="server"  
    NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("cats", new {ct = Eval("Category_Id"), catname = Eval("Category_Name")}) %>'> 
     Link Text 
</asp:HyperLink>
```

[See also here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: ok i tried this but didnt work.it said `resource not found` so i added a `/` even in MapPageRoutes method like `routes.MapPageRoute("cats","/Categories/{ct}/{catname}","~/catwise.aspx");` but that throws compile time error it says `url cannot start with ~ or /`.

Comment: @VishalRavlani you don't need to change your route, it's just the way you generate your URLs.

Comment: @james : can you please show me the how should i do it..because i have been searching for url rewriting and url routing for 3 days but didnt find any proper resource so i decided to use url routing. and it seems to be easy. but in no article i have found a solution. and this is my first website i am developing and m having no knowledge about routing.

Comment: I am sure there is plenty resources out there. See the link I mention. I also edited my post and the example I gave at the end should work as it is.

Comment: @lalibi: k i tried.. but in my case as you can sees that apple(category name) and 1(category id) both are coming from database. so when i did this with values from database it didnt work and error said bad request because data isnt getting evaled

Comment: @lalibi : `<% Request.ApplicationPath %>/Categories/ ` has solved the problem..thanx for your replies.

Comment: You should know that this is bad practice. In case you change the route later the link will probably break. Treating routes properly (like using the GetRouteUrl function) will help you avoid bugs in the future. I don't mind about excepting my answer, but I encourage you to try the solution I propose.

Comment: thanx lalibi..coz `Request.ApplicationPath` didn't work on hosting server..so i used `GetRouteUrl`..

Answer (score 0):

When you create links like `Categories/1/Apple` it is treated as relative from the current URL, you need to add a backslash to be beginning of the URL e.g. `/Categories/1/Apple`, this ensures your URLs are relative to the root.

**Update**

Based on your comment  "*home page url is `http://localhost:14268/mysite`*" it would appear your site is running under a Virtual Directory. Therefore, simply adding `/` to the URLs won't work, you need to explictly prepend the path to your VD to the URL e.g.

```
<% Request.ApplicationPath %>/Categories/...
```

Comment: whenevr i am adding `/` i dont know why but it gives error that `resource not found`

Comment: thank you `<% Request.ApplicationPath %>` did the trick..but i had to accept the answer of OP because he answered this solution first....but thank you very much

Comment: @VishalRavlani no problem, if you had mentioned the site was running under a VD I would have answered that first time though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<a href="<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>/Categories/<%# Eval("Category_Id")%>/<%# Eval("Category_Name")%>">
```

The `<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>` should resolve to a relative path pointing to the application root...

Comment: m sorry to say that i have to unaccept this as an answer because your solution did work on locally but didn't work on hosting server...so i had to use `GetRouteUrl`..

Comment: Interesting... But of course you should not accept it if it did not work.

Comment: the problem was i was testing it on `local` and it was working perfect,so i accepted your answer i thought if its working on local,it will work on hosting server too..but when uploaded it on the hosting server it was not working...so i had to use other solution..sorry for the misunderstanding.